# Android Listview and media player service

Tags: android, listview, service, media-player

I currently have a `listview` and when a user presses an item on the list it loads up a new `activity` which starts and binds to a `service`. When, i press back to go to the `listview` and I press the same item again, i am getting an `unable to destroy activity` error. any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you didn't post any code for us to look at, I'm guessing that you never unbind your `Service`.  You can find the same issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/valkyrie-android/issues/detail?id=8).

Comment: That did the trick. You have to use `getApplicationContext().` before unbind and stop service